# In a fourier series if $a_0$ is equal to 0 is $a_n$ also equal to 0?

Tags: fourier-series

When im trying to determine a fourier series if I determin the $a_0$ is 0 does it follow that $a_n$ must also be 0?

Comment: Why it would be so?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): edit your post to include **some work**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example is the function $f(x) = \cos x$ with period $2\pi$.  In this case, the coefficient $a_0 = 0$ but $a_1 = 1$.

---

Maybe I can guess your reason for the question: if $f(x) \ge 0$, then
$a_0 = 0$ is
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)\;dx= 0
$$
and (since $f(x) \ge 0$) that does, indeed, imply $f(x) = 0$ for almost all $x$.  And then we conclude that all Fourier coefficients are $0$.

Comment: Does such a no-effort question really deserve an answer? Shouldn't we rather encourage the posters to share their thoughts? Imo, it would be as useful for them as for future readers.